# Cannot delete file when used in DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

My application shows images on screen (images based upon files on the local computer) and users can delete them if needed.

Every time I try to delete a file it results in the following error message:

```
"The process cannot access the file 'C:\\Users\\Dave\\Desktop\\Duplicate\\Swim.JPG' because it is being used by another process."
```

I understand the error message.

I have a `UserControl` which accepts a file path (via a parameter in the constructor) and then binds it to it's (UserControl) `DataContext`.

As part of debugging this issue I have found the issue is due to setting the DataContext within the UserControl. If I remove `this.DataContext = this;` from within my UserControl then I can delete the file.

So, my TestUnit looks like

```
        Ui.UserControls.ImageControl ic = new ImageControl(
           @"C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\Duplicate\Swim.JPG");

        try
        {
            File.Delete(@"C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\Duplicate\Swim.JPG");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Assert.Fail(ex.Message);
        }
```

The UserControl CodeBehind

```
    public ImageControl(string path)
    {
        this.FilePath = path;
        this.DataContext = this; // removing this line allows me to delete the file!
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    #region Properties

    private string _filePath;
    public string FilePath
    {
        get { return _filePath; }
        set
        {
            _filePath = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FilePath");
        }
    }
```

If it matters, my UserControl XAML is using the 'Image' control, bound to 'FilePath'

I have tried making the UserControl null before deleting, this did not help.

I have tried adding the IDisposible Interface to my UserControl and within the `Dispose()` method setting `this.DataContext = null;` but this did not help.

What am I doing wrong? How can I delete this file (or more accurately, make it unused).

Comment: Try setting the FilePath null before deleting.

Comment: Hi @Blam, by setting `this.DataContext =null;` it FilePath is null  (FilePath is a property). However, to be really sure, I also tried manually setting it to null and sadly it made no difference.

Comment: Setting DataContext to null and never assigning it are not the same.

Comment: @Blam, Yes, you're right, that's 100% the problem. I can't find any documentation though to say how to "un-assign" it after is has been assigned (or what is keeping a reference to my FilePath)! I've tried making the properties null manually and via the datacontext, neither worked.

Comment: Nor, does making the object null!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image file copy, is being used by another process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18167280/image-file-copy-is-being-used-by-another-process)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not the DataContext, but simply the way WPF loads images from files.

When you bind the `Source` property of an Image control to a string that contains a file path, WPF internally creates a new BitmapFrame object from the path basically like this:

```
string path = ...
var bitmapImage = BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri(path));
```

Unfortunately this keeps the Image file opened by WPF, so that you can't delete it.

To get around this you have to change the type of your image property to `ImageSource` (or a derived type) and load the image manually like shown below.

```
public ImageSource ImageSource { get; set; } // omitted OnPropertyChanged for brevity

private ImageSource LoadImage(string path)
{
    var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

    using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
    {
        bitmapImage.BeginInit();
        bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmapImage.StreamSource = stream;
        bitmapImage.EndInit();
        bitmapImage.Freeze(); // optional
    }

    return bitmapImage;
}

...
ImageSource = LoadImage(@"C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\Duplicate\Swim.JPG");
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but as a follow up, how do you know this is what WPF does? There appears to be some magic/witch craft around this community... Did you de-assemble the WPF dll's, or is the WPF code freely available to see this behaviour?

Comment: Actually I don't know if that is exactly what WPF does. But if you take a debugger and look at the value of the Image.Source property when it is bound to a string, you see that it contains a BitmapFrameDecode instance, which is exactly what BitmapFrame.Create returns. Checking the other way round and calling BitmapFrame.Create with a local file Uri keeps the file open. Of course you could still use a tool like .NET Reflector and disassemble the TypeConverter for ImageSource to see what WPF is really doing.