# WPF BitmapImage Doesn't Dispose

Tags: wpf, filestream, idisposable

I have  loaded a list of images out of a filestream database. When I load them initially the memory jump isn't that large. When I display them on the screen my memory usage spikes and doesn't go away even after I dispose of the BitmapImage streamsource and set it to Nothing.

```
    Dim newItem As New MIdentifiedImage
    Dim data As Byte() = dt.Rows(i).Item("ScannedImage")
    Dim strm As New MemoryStream(data)

    Dim bi As New BitmapImage()
    bi.BeginInit()
    bi.StreamSource = strm
    bi.EndInit()
    bi.Freeze()
    newItem.ScannedImage = bi
```

And here is my dispose code

```
  For Each img In InvoiceObj.ImageList
    img.ScannedImage.StreamSource.Dispose()
    img.ScannedImage.StreamSource = Nothing

  Next
```

So my profiler says that the memory usage is low but when I check in my task manager the memory usage is quite high. If I continue to load images beyond 1.5GB of memory it just stops showing the images on screen.

Comment: In addition to what Reed has said, if you'd set `bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad` before calling EndInit, you could dispose of the stream immediately, like shown e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19347459/1136211).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to clear out the `ImageList`, as well.  Just setting the `StreamSource` to `null` doesn't cause it to remove the data that's already loaded.  By clearing the `ImageList` when you're done with it, you allow the GC to clean up the actual `BitmapImage` instances, as well.