# Cannot delete image after inserting on a word document at a specific location c# & spire.doc

Tags: c#, image, ms-word, office-interop, spire.doc

```
var getImage = model.Document.Get().Where(x => x.ReferenceNo == ReferenceNo && x.ChecklistId == 225).FirstOrDefault();
var Imagefilename = path + "\\" + ReferenceNo.Replace("/", "_") + "IdentityPhoto.Jpg";

var filebytes = ConvertToBytes(getImage.FileData);
using (var filestream = new FileStream(Imagefilename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    filestream.Write(filebytes, 0, filebytes.Length);
    filestream.Close();
    filestream.Dispose();
}
using (Spire.Doc.Document document = new Spire.Doc.Document(@OpenTemplate))
{
    Spire.Doc.Section section = document.Sections[0];
    System.Drawing.Bitmap p = new Bitmap(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@Imagefilename));
    // p.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipX);
    Spire.Doc.Fields.DocPicture picture = document.Sections[0].Paragraphs[0].AppendPicture(p);

    // set image's position
    picture.HorizontalPosition = 370.0F;
    picture.VerticalPosition = 480.0F;

    // set image's size
    picture.Width = 80;
    picture.Height = 80;

    // set textWrappingStyle with image;
    picture.TextWrappingStyle = Spire.Doc.Documents.TextWrappingStyle.Through;

    // Save doc file.
    document.SaveToFile(@Demo, Spire.Doc.FileFormat.Docx);
    p.Dispose();
    document.Dispose();
    document.Close();
}

// Trying to delete this file 
try
{
    if (File.Exists(Imagefilename))
    {  
        File.Delete(Imagefilename);   
    }
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exception);
}
```

Using a Word document as template, image is retrieved from database. It is stored on the C drive, the image at that location is then being used and inserted into a word document.

When trying to delete the image from the drive after use it keeps on throwing an error:

> Error message "process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

I have tried using `.Dispose` and `.Close` functions and using statements. I have tried `Directory.Delete` but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Try using the 'alternative method' mentioned in this answer: [Image file copy, is being used by another process](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18167419/6741868).